# Decreasing order of occurrence

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I want to get the integer with decreasing order of their occurrence in the array. If the count of occurrence matches then bigger integer get the preference. I am getting wrong output. Can you please help me on this.

input-

```
5
6 1 2 1 2
```

output-

```
2 1 6
```

Code in Python:-

```
n=int(input())
a=list(map(int,input().strip().split()))
for i in range(n):
    c=1
    for j in range(i+1,n):
        if(a[i]==a[j]): 
            c+=1
    sorted(a,reverse=True)
    print(a)
```

Comment: `sorted` doesn't modify the in-place, but rather returns a new list. It might not resolve your issue, but try `a = sorted(a,reverse=True)`

Comment: ```collections.Counter([6, 1, 2, 1, 2]).most_common(3)```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the order where count is even, you can use this:

```
sorted(set(a), key=a.count, reverse=True)

# [1, 2, 6]
```